# Countable union of closed sets - not closed

Tags: real-analysis

An example for a countable union of closed sets is

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{k},1-\frac{1}{k}]=(0,1),$$

but why is $[0,1]$ not in the union?  $\lim _{k\to \infty}[\frac{1}{k},1-\frac{1}{k}]=[0,1]?$

Comment: $\lim_{k\to \infty}[1/k,1-1/k]$ is gibberish.

Comment: A point $p$ belongs to the union $\cup F$ of a family $F$ of sets iff $p$ belongs to at least one member $f$ of $F.$ That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$[0,1]$ is not in the union, because $0,1\not\in\left[\dfrac1k,1-\dfrac1k\right]$ for any $k$.

Comment: just as $lim f(x)=a$ does not mean that $f(a)\in f(x)$?

Comment: And what does $f(a)\in f(x)$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

$0 \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{k}, 1-\frac{1}{k}]$ iff there is some $k \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that $0 \in [\frac{1}{k}, 1-\frac{1}{k}]$. This is the **definition** of a union.

But for all such $k$, $\frac{1}{k}>0$, so $0 \notin [\frac{1}{k}, 1-\frac{1}{k}]$ so $0$ is not in the union.

The same goes for $1$ as $1-\frac{1}{k}< 1$ for all such $k$ and so $1 \notin [\frac{1}{k}, 1-\frac{1}{k}]$ as well.

But do note that if $x>0$ is fixed, then for some large enough $k$ we will have $0< \frac{1}{k} < x$ (e.g. by applying the definition of the limit $\lim_k \frac{1}{k} = 0$ to epsilon value $x$, or applying the Archimedean property of the reals) and so $x \in [\frac{1}{k}, 1-\frac{1}{k}]$ for such large $k$ and $x$ is in the union. Hence the fact that the union is exactly $(0,1)$ (a similar argument can be held for $x < 1$ as for $x>0$).